# Linking 2 Mongoose collections

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I am trying to build a simple website, where authenticated users (authors) can write and post stories.
I have an Author collection and a Story collection and I'm trying to create links between both collections. I am using mongoose and the populate/ref method. I can successfully display a story or list of stories that contain information about their author but I'm really struggling to attach a list of stories to their author when displaying the author profile. What I want is to make sure that when visiting an author profile page, users can see the list of their stories.

I'm trying to use the populate/ref method to fulfill the array that would display the authors list of stories (storyList) but the array remains tirelessly empty. When displaying an author profile page I first used the findById function but understood this doesn't seem to work with populate. So I'm now using the findOne function but with the same results.

Here is my Author collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const authorSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  authorImage: {
    type: String
  },
  emailAddress: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  storyList: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Story'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema, 'authors');
```

Here is my route to display an author profile page:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const Author = require('../models/author');

exports.authors_get_one = (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.params.userName;
  Author.findOne(username)
    .select("_id userName firstName lastName emailAddress password authorImage storyList")
    .populate('storyList')
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
      console.log("From database", doc);
      if (doc) {
        res.status(200).json({
          author: doc,
        });
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: 'No valid entry found for provided ID'
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
}
```

Here is my Story schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const storySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Author',
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  language: {
    type: String,
  },
  published: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema, 'stories');
```

And here is my route to create a story:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Story = require('../models/story');
const Author = require('../models/author');

exports.stories_createOne = (req, res, next) => {
  const story = new Story({
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text,
    language: req.body.language,
    author: req.body.author
  });
  story
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Story publiée !",
        createdStory: {
          _id: result._id,
          title: result.title,
          text: result.text,
          language: result.language,
          author: result.author,
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
}
```

From the documentation I found, I can not see what I'm doing wrong. Am I missing something here? Is the populate method not enough to fulfill my list of stories (storyList)? Should I even do something somewhere else in my code and what?

Comment: How is your `Story` schema ?

Comment: Hi @whoami, thanks for your comment, I have added the Story schema and the route to create a story in my initial question

Comment: Can you change this `mongoose.model('Story', storySchema, 'stories')` to `mongoose.model('Story', storySchema, 'Story')` & try your `findOne` query on `Author`..

Comment: I've just tried but same result.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `storyList` array remains empty is because you are not pushing the stories ref into the `author.storyList` array after creating the stories. [Source](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children).

The easy fix to this would be to do something like this in the route to create a story:

```
exports.stories_createOne = (req, res, next) => {
  const story = new Story({
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text,
    language: req.body.language,
    author: req.body.author
  });
  story
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      // Push the story id into the author.storyList array
      Author
        .update(
          { _id: req.body.author }, 
          { $push: { storyList: result.toJSON()._id } }
         )
        .then(() => {
          // send response here
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Handle Error
    });
}
```

Comment: Amazing, it is working indeed! I had actually tried this $push method before but didn't use it properly. Many thanks for your help!